# What's the version of Netty in RESTEasy?

Tags: netty, resteasy

RESTEasy has an embedded Netty, but the documents do not show the version of Netty.

How could I know the Netty version?

Comment: Let me know if my answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which module you are using to integrate with Netty:

- [RESTEasy Netty Integration 3.0.16.Final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-netty/3.0.16.Final) ([`resteasy-netty`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-netty) artifact) includes [Netty 3.6.4.Final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty/3.6.4.Final).
- [RESTEasy Netty 4 Integration 3.0.16.Final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-netty4/3.0.16.Final) ([`resteasy-netty4`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-netty4) artifact) includes [Netty 4.0.7.Final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.7.Final).

Other versions of the integration module might use different versions of Netty. For more details, check the dependencies of the integration modules:

- [`resteasy-netty`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-netty)
- [`resteasy-netty4`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-netty4)